# There was an error generating the XML document- Working Class

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, msmq

I have the following C# code of a class which I create an object of that I am trying to send in a MessageQueue that keeps giving me the InvalidOperationException "There was an error generating the XML document" that I cannot figure out how to get rid of.  What am I doing wrong?

```
[Serializable()]
public class InMessage : ISerializable
{
    public bool IsSubscription;
    public String Type;
    public DateTime TimeStamp;
    public String SenderID;
    public Object Content;


    public InMessage()
    {
        IsSubscription = false;
        Type = "";
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        SenderID = "";
        Content = "";
    }

    public InMessage(bool isSubscription, String type, DateTime timeStamp, String senderID, Object content)
    {
        IsSubscription = isSubscription;
        Type = type;
        TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        SenderID = senderID;
        Content = content;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        info.AddValue("IsSubscription", IsSubscription);
        info.AddValue("Type", Type);
        info.AddValue("TimeStamp", TimeStamp);
        info.AddValue("SenderID", SenderID);
        info.AddValue("Content", Content);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the inner exception? There's usually a chain of inner exceptions, telling you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Also, please show the code you're using to serialize.

Comment: I think the object you pass to `Content` causes that error. Try to pass a null and see whether you still get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was actually irrelevant to this class but was a problem with the formatter.